# wxDEV+OpenCV error : Undefined reference to `cvLoadImage''

Tags: opencv, wxwidgets

**Hello everyone, I am trying to use OpenCV library in wxDev C++, and it couldn't compiler correctly. (OpenCV version: 2.4.13.4)**

These are the errors:

```
[Linker Error] undefined reference to `cvLoadImage'
[Linker Error] undefined reference to `cvShowImage'
[Linker Error] undefined reference to `cvWaitKey'
[Linker Error] undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
ld returned 1 exit status
```

These are the codes:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
int main()
    {
    IplImage *srcImg = NULL;

    srcImg = cvLoadImage( "temp.jpg", 1);
    if( srcImg == NULL ){
    return -1;
    }

    cvShowImage( "Source", srcImg ); 
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage( &srcImg );
    }
```

These are the setting of wxDev:
[wxDev Compiler Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2cAJ.jpg)

**It seems that wxDev can't recognize those methods which I included from the library. What should I do?**

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[12/4 update] I forgot to say that I've tried to use a different version of OpenCV(3.3.1) as well, so the settings in the screenshot have a little bug. "D:\OpenCV\2.4\opencv\build" is for 2.4.13.4. "D:\OpenCV\opencv\build" is for 3.3.1. I have included both of them in the setting but still doesn't work out. I don't know what is the differences between 3.3.1 and 2.4.1.3, but they are the newest update then.

I've tried to change the way I named the libraries, but it didn't work. For instance, "-opencv_core", "-lopencv_core", "-opencv_core.lib", "-lopencv_core.lib", "-lopencv_core.a".

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[12/5 update#1] It seems that there is something wrong with the libraries. So, instead of using the newer version of OpenCV, I tried using the older one, the OpenCV2.2. Fortunately, it worked pretty well! I did exactly the same thing but came out a different result. I assumed that the methods of the software have been modified somehow in the latest version. Hopefully, someone could provide a later tutorial for the recent version of OpenCV.

[12/5 update#2] After successfully compiler this program, I started running another OpenCV example. The same issues occurred.

Example Code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main(){
    Mat img = imread("lena.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    imwrite("output.jpg",img);  

    namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);  
    imshow("Display window", img);        
    waitKey(0);                          

    return 0;
}
```

Some of those errors:

```
[Linker Error] undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)
[Linker Error] undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)
[Linker Error] undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)
[Linker Error] undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
```

**The same problem just keep happening, still looking for savior.**

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[12/6 update] After several attempts, I downgraded OpenCV into version 2.0. The program successfully worked. The only difference compared to the other versions is the library's direction which was included.

The other version won't work if I write `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`.
Version 2.0 will work if I write `#include <cv.h>, #include <highgui.h>`.
(Version 2.0 doesn't have the file, `opencv2`, so I have to include the direction.) I have no idea why it ends up like this.

**The solution is to use the version 2.0 and also not using `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`. It can run perfectly well in most of the examples so far.** Although I could start working on my project now, I still try to figure out how to use the latest version of OpenCV.

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Respond to *Mark Setchell*-
These are the screenshots of the files and settings so far:

[The lib files and its directions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2QB5.jpg)

[OpenCV 2.2.0 settings and directions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpNZn.jpg)

[OpenCV 2.4.11 settings and directions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E65Rp.jpg)

I have tried different versions of OpenCV to run the program, the details of the process written in "12/5 update". By the way, I did change the compiler before running the program. Thanks for helping!

Comment: This is a typical error you would get when either you are not linking the library files correctly or your compilation of OpenCV was not correctly done. I might be wrong but it seems you are using MinGW as your compiler but trying to use OpenCV compiled for Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I’m not sure if I get what you mean, but I am using wxDev C++ for this project, not Visual Studio. Honestly, I have no idea what is MinGW for, it was a default setting.

Comment: Your library files cannot have file extension .lib, it should be .a. If you were using visual studio you could have used .lib.

Comment: I don't know wxDev++ but elsewhere you might use `-lopencv_core` or `-llibopencv_core` or `-lopencv_core.a` etc.

Comment: Sure, I will try it out then!

Comment: Please show output from `DIR D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib`

Comment: @MarkSetchell The screenshots are right above, check it whether it is right.

Answer (score 0):

The opencv-libs are missing. In your screenshow you have add the folders, but the names in your config are defined as **-opencv_core...** . Normally the option for linking them is -L, even in wxDev++. So just add the libs like:

```
-Lopencv_core2413.lib
```

Comment: I named it in different ways, "-Lopencv_core2413.lib", "-Lopencv_core2413". It still not working, but still thanks for your help!

Comment: Just check the lib folder of opencv if there are any subfolders for x86 or x64, I made this error so often...

Comment: OK, I will recheck all the links again in case I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

According to you source code, you forgot to use the opencv namespace.

If your librarys are all linked correctly, try to add `using namespace cv;`

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    IplImage *srcImg = NULL;

    srcImg = cvLoadImage( "temp.jpg", 1);
    if( srcImg == NULL ){
        return -1;
    }

    cvShowImage( "Source", srcImg ); 
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage( &srcImg );
}
```

or use it explicitly:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
int main()
{
    cv::IplImage *srcImg = NULL;

    srcImg = cv::cvLoadImage( "temp.jpg", 1);
    if( srcImg == NULL ){
        return -1;
    }

    cv::cvShowImage( "Source", srcImg ); 
    cv::cvWaitKey(0);
    cv::cvReleaseImage( &srcImg );
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It seems you are right, I should add the namespace for the program. However, The same errors still exist. Anyway, thanks for your help!